# Deleting a row in Master view in Master detail view based app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, native, master-detail

I am developing a Master-Detail bas iPhone native app.

I have a delete button in Detail view which should delete the corresponding row in Master view that was tapped by the user.

I don't want to give delete option in Master view.

Is this achievable ? if yes how ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider you have table view in master and once you click on row detail view is displayed.

In this, yes, you can give delete button in detail view.

Consider you have an NSMutableArray which is displayed in table.
On click of delete button delete  particular entry in array.

then reload data in table.

Comment: I am not able to reload the data in MasterTableView using [self.tableview reload]

Comment: write it in -(void)viewWillAppear